# Why Teamcity doesn't recognize robot command?

Tags: teamcity, robotframework

I decided to use Teamcity as my CI/CD tool for robot framework tests.
My robot tests are working normally when I run them via CMD, but with these cmd settings in Team city:
*cd \TestSuites\BasicTests* 
*robot Connectivity.robot*
my test fails with this message in log:
**'robot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**

Any ideas?

Comment: You either haven't installed robot on the teamcity server, or the user that teamcity uses doesn't have its PATH set properly

Comment: Teamcity is currently installed locally, so the robot framework is installed on the same machine as Teamcity is running on, but I am not sure, what do you mean, that the path is not set properly.

Comment: have you tried: `python|jython|ipy|pypy -m robot` instead of robot?

Comment: yes, I've tried also those, but the message was the same, but only for python etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in users. Solved via Team City Agent service. So it could be solved via *services.msc* -> find TeamCity *Build Agent* service -> right click and select Properties -> change your *Log on* option to *This account* and fill up required information -> confirm

This solved my problem